# REST service-Post image(stream content) and filename-- Error

Tags: wcf, rest, post, stream

As per requirement I need a rest WCF service to Post an image and file Name from Iphone. I have created a Rest service. But when I run the WCF service I am getting following error

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:IService1 ----> System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation PostImage to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.ValidateAndGetStreamPart(MessageDescription messageDescription, Boolean isRequest, String operationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.Create(MessageDescription messageDescription, String operationName, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExportContract(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportContract(ContractDescription contract)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I have used following code

```
[OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                    UriTemplate = "PostImage/{filename}",
                    Method = "POST")]
  string PostImage(string filename, Stream obj);


  public string PostImage(string filename, Stream obj)
  {
  }
```

And using the following web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingStreamed" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00"></binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="Test.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
      contract="Test.IService1" 
      behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
      bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingStreamed"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp" >
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am struggling with this error.
Any one have any idea about this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This blog explains why this error could be thrown in your REST service. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2010/03/02/how-to-solve-system-invalidoperationexception-for-request-in-operation-test-to-be-a-stream-the-operation-must-have-a-single-parameter-whose-type-is-stream.aspx

[Snippet from blog]
If this is a REST endpoint, this programming model is actually supported because REST has its own formatter which handles multiple parameters correctly. However, if you continue to see this issue, then please make sure your WebHttpBehavior is set up correctly. Possible reason for not having that behavior set up correctly could be:

1. You are using a custom behavior, and its endpoint does not have the correct the contract name matching with the WCF contract;
2. You are not using WebEndpoint or WebServiceHost;

You can also workaround this issue by choosing Buffered option in the TransferMode on the binding. But that seems to be defeating the whole purpose of the Streaming.

Question is : Is your service host WebServiceHost?

Comment: Now I hosted the service in local IIS